# Add parameters to quartz scheduler using xml

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have the current job and trigger in my servlet.xml

```
<bean id="actualizacionAsistencias" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="asistenciasManager" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run" />
</bean?

<bean id="asistenciasTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="actualizacionAsistencias" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 1 1 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Is there any way to add a parameter? I need the method 'run' to recive 'true' (boolean) when executed.

Answer (score 5):

Following the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.html) of the bean class, it seems that it extends the normal MethodInvoker which has a property arguments. This means that the following should work (not tested):

```
<bean id="actualizacionAsistencias" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="asistenciasManager" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>true</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean?

<bean id="asistenciasTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="actualizacionAsistencias" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 1 1 * * ?" />
</bean>
```